# HTML text-alignment issues on transforms

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, text-alignment

I am trying to render a line of transformed text in html/css, however I've had some issues. When I scale the Y direction the overall alignment of the elements shifts as in this picture.

[image]

Trying to just rotate the L 180 degrees results in the same error. How do I maintain the vertical alignment on y-scaling axis for the text? Let's say i also do this with a small caps, any changes for your solution?

What's going wrong here?

```html
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #reflect{
     display: flex;
     flex-basis: auto;
    }
    #reflectl {
     /*transform: scaleX(-1) !important;*/
     transform: scale3d(-1,-1, 1);  !important;
    }
    #reflecte {
       transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
    }
    #reflectc {
       transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
    }
</style>

<text id=reflect>
  <text id="reflectref">REF</text>
  <text id="reflectl">L</text>
  <text id="reflecte">E</text>
  <text id="reflectc">C</text>
  <text id="reflectt" >T</text>
</text>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the element is taller than the text it contains, so when you rotate, the center of rotation is not exactly in the middle, so when it's done the text is slightly off.  Simplest solution would be to set the height of the elements to exactly the height that it needs.

```html
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #reflect{
     display: flex;
     flex-basis: auto;
    }
    #reflect text {
        height: 17px;
    }
    #reflectl {
     /*transform: scaleX(-1) !important;*/
     transform: scale3d(-1,-1, 1);  !important;
    }
    #reflecte {
       transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
    }
    #reflectc {
       transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
    }
</style>

<text id=reflect>
  <text id="reflectref">REF</text>
  <text id="reflectl">L</text>
  <text id="reflecte">E</text>
  <text id="reflectc">C</text>
  <text id="reflectt" >T</text>
</text>
```

```html
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #reflect{
     display: flex;
     flex-basis: auto;
    }
    #reflect text {
        height: 17px;
    }
    #reflectl {
     /*transform: scaleX(-1) !important;*/
     transform: scale3d(-1,-1, 1);  !important;
    }
    #reflecte {
       transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
    }
    #reflectc {
       transform: scaleX(-1) !important;
    }
</style>

<text id=reflect>
  <text id="reflectref">ref</text>
  <text id="reflectl">l</text>
  <text id="reflecte">e</text>
  <text id="reflectc">c</text>
  <text id="reflectt" >t</text>
</text>
```

Comment: I tried this on the browser I originally wrote this question on and it seems to be functional. However, running an older version of firefox on my VM (firefox 44), this renders now with the L too high up, so it doesn't seem to be fixing the core problem. This also causes the results to more dramatically fail on small caps text.

Comment: to follow up more. Apparently this is effected by font sizes. I've gotten correct rotations on intervals of 12.